# Show next available invoice number

Tags: excel

In worksheet "Orders" I have available invoice numbers in column A and customer names in column D. I currently allocate a customer name manually to the next available invoice number.

```
  A       D
1234   Fred Smith
1235   Bill Jones
1236
1237
```

On another worksheet I wish to display the next available invoice number, that is the next unused one with no name already allocated to it (1236 in the example above). What method can I use to pull this data in? Sorry for no example as I'm a bit unsure which command would suit this instance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are the assigned names in column D consecutive - or could there be "holes", i.e. could there be a name for 1237?

Comment: @PeterAlbert No, there is never any data below the last one in the example above

Comment: then use the first formula from my answer! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=INDEX(Orders!$A:$A,COUNTA(Orders!$D:$D)+1)
```

This assumes that column D contains no "holes". If this is the case, try this formula

```
=INDEX(Orders!$A:$A,MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(Orders!$D:$D),0))
```

Enter the latter formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Using your first formula I appear to be 1 number less than the next available number, but it works. There is a column title in row 1 (Order number, Name etc). Can I add 1 somehow?

Comment: yes, simply add `+1`! I forgot about that. Answer is updated, sorry!